# Unable to position XML Attributes at proper location of my Java created XML Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization

This is the XML output I currently get:

```
<parameter>
  <dataIdentifier>123</dataIdentifier>
  <newValue encoding="base64">
     <value>NjUw</value>
  </newValue>
</parameter>
```

And this is the XML output I want to have:

```
<parameter>
  <dataIdentifier>123</dataIdentifier>
  <newValue encoding="base64">NjUw</newValue>
</parameter>
```

Here are my Java classes so far:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "parameter")
public class Parameter {

    private Integer dataIdentifier;
    private ParameterValue newValue;
  ..
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ParameterValue {

    @XmlAttribute(name="encoding") 
    private String encoding;
    private String value;
  ..
}
```

I am sure there is an easy solution for my problem. Unfortunately I do not have any idea about JAXB annotations.
I already invested a few hours but I can't find a way to do it. Can someone please show me how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like the XML attribute (`encoding`) is the problem, but the `value` field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use following class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ParameterValue {

    @XmlAttribute(name="encoding") private String encoding;
    @XmlValue private String value;
  ..
}
```

Comment: Hi Xstian, many, many thanks! Life can be so easy sometimes. It works now! Will accept this as answer, when stackoverflow has unlocked the answer field